# How can I move a JsArray to the root with Json Transformers within a Json object?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, transformer-model

How can I move a `JsArray` to the root with [Json Transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)? Imagine a Json structure like so:

```
   {
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : {
       "key21" : "catface",
       "key22" : true,
       "key23" : [
           {
              "key231": "alpha", 
              "key232": "beta", 
              "key232": "gamma"
           },
           ...
       ],
       "key24" : 234
    }
```

If I wanted to move `key21` to the root then I would use - `__.json.copyFrom((__ \ 'key2 \ 'key21).json.pick)` but if I wanted to move `key23` to the root; i.e.

```
   {
     "key23" : [
       {
          "key231": "alpha", 
          "key232": "beta", 
          "key232": "gamma"
       },
       ...
     ]
   }
```

but `__.json.copyFrom((__ \ 'key2 \ 'key23).json.pick)` causes the error:

> A server errors occurred: when empty JsPath, expecting JsObject

So then I try `__.json.copyFrom((__ \ 'key2 \ 'key23).json.pick[JsArray])` or `__.json.copyFrom[JsArray]((__ \ 'key2 \ 'key23).json.pick[JsArray])` - but the same error

I couldn't find anything out there that addresses this specifically but I am hoping this is an easy one for someone. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value you're picking needs a new key under root

```
(__ \ 'key23).json.copyFrom((__ \ 'key2 \ 'key23).json.pick)
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wDW7cWT3SeaPrYEbumrtxA)

Comment: ahh - of course! Easy points - just think that the `JsArray` threw me. One up as well for the test area link. Thank-you!